# Converting long datetime into date (dd/mm/yyyy)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

In a CSV file, I have two date formats: `05/02/1980` and `2022-07-30T10:00:20.973235`

I'd like to convert them to `yyyy/mm/dd` dates types.

I've tried `to_datetime` and `parse_dates=` to no avail.

Any ideas?

```py
import pandas as pd
from dateutil.relativedelta import *
from datetime import *

Retrieve data from the vaccination CSV
df = pd.read_csv("metabase_data/vaccinations/query.csv", usecols=[2,3,4,5,8,9,10])
df = df.rename(columns={'First Name': 'firstName', 'Last Name': 'lastName', 'Dob': 'dob', 'Reservation Number': 'reservation', 'Sec On D/ Last Vaccination Date': 'vaccinationDate', 'Vaccination Proof Uploaded Date Time' : 'dateTimeUploaded', 'Club Name':'voyageId'})
```

CSV extract

| ID | Profile ID | First Name | Last Name | Dob | Reservation Number | Type | Fir St/ Last Vaccination Date | Sec On D/ Last Vaccination Date | Vaccination Proof Uploaded Date Time | Club Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| dfgfgh | ccbvcf | JASON | CHAMBERS | 05/02/1980 | 45544 | P |  | 23/04/2012 | 2022-07-30T10:00:20.973235 | rt1377 |
| dfgnhvn | hnghn | HEATHERE | JACOBSON | 28/05/1983 | 34646 | P |  | 07/01/2001 | 2022-07-30T09:57:45.614589 | rt1377 |
| vhnghgh | vnvn | JASMINE | JACOBSON | 28/08/2004 | 45656 | P |  | 30/04/2011 | 2022-07-30T09:56:29.322404 | rt1377 |

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the format of `05/02/1980`?

Comment: It's dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: if you can post an example of ```query.csv```, it could be helpful

Comment: Sure. Dummy CSV added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your Dataframe :

```
    ID      Profile ID  First Name  Last Name   Dob Reservation Number  Type    Fir St/ Last Vaccination Date   Sec On D/ Last Vaccination Date Vaccination Proof Uploaded Date Time    Club Name
0   dfgfgh  ccbvcf      JASON       CHAMBERS    05/02/1980      45544   P       NaN                             23/04/2012                      2022-07-30T10:00:20.973235              rt1377
1   dfgnhvn hnghn       HEATHERE    JACOBSON    28/05/1983      34646   P       NaN                             07/01/2001                      2022-07-30T09:57:45.614589              rt1377
2   vhnghgh vnvn        JASMINE     JACOBSON    28/08/2004      45656   P       NaN                             30/04/2011                      2022-07-30T09:56:29.322404              rt1377
```

We can use [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) to convert the date to Datetime with two differents formats to get the expected result :

```py
df['Sec On D/ Last Vaccination Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Sec On D/ Last Vaccination Date'], format="%d/%m/%Y")
df['Vaccination Proof Uploaded Date Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Vaccination Proof Uploaded Date Time'], format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")
```

Output :

```
    ID      Profile ID  First Name  Last Name   Dob Reservation Number  Type    Fir St/ Last Vaccination Date   Sec On D/ Last Vaccination Date Vaccination Proof Uploaded Date Time    Club Name
0   dfgfgh  ccbvcf      JASON       CHAMBERS    05/02/1980      45544   P       NaN                             2012-04-23                      2022-07-30T10:00:20.973235              rt1377
1   dfgnhvn hnghn       HEATHERE    JACOBSON    28/05/1983      34646   P       NaN                             2001-01-07                      2022-07-30T09:57:45.614589              rt1377
2   vhnghgh vnvn        JASMINE     JACOBSON    28/08/2004      45656   P       NaN                             2011-04-30                      2022-07-30T09:56:29.322404              rt1377
```

To shorten the datetime with hours to the date only, we can use `dt.date` like so :

```py
df['Vaccination Proof Uploaded Date Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Vaccination Proof Uploaded Date Time'], format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f").dt.date
```

Output :

```
    ID      Profile ID  First Name  Last Name   Dob Reservation Number  Type    Fir St/ Last Vaccination Date   Sec On D/ Last Vaccination Date Vaccination Proof Uploaded Date Time    Club Name
0   dfgfgh  ccbvcf      JASON       CHAMBERS    05/02/1980      45544   P       NaN                             2012-04-23                      2022-07-30                              rt1377
1   dfgnhvn hnghn       HEATHERE    JACOBSON    28/05/1983      34646   P       NaN                             2001-01-07                      2022-07-30                              rt1377
2   vhnghgh vnvn        JASMINE     JACOBSON    28/08/2004      45656   P       NaN                             2011-04-30                      2022-07-30                              rt1377
```

Comment: How could I shorten date2 to yyyy-mm-dd?

Comment: Hi @StevenDiffey, I updated the answer with your csv extract, hope it helps :) ! I wish you a great day !

Comment: I just updated the answer to show how to shorten the date to yy-mm-dd, hope it helps my friend :) !

Answer (score 2):

`pd.to_datetime` can infer datetime type, you can use

```py
date1 = pd.to_datetime('05/02/1980', dayfirst=True)
date2 = pd.to_datetime('2022-07-30T10:00:20.973235')
```

```
print(date1)

1980-02-05 00:00:00


print(date2)

2022-07-30 10:00:20.973235
```